# Regex: Reoccuring pattern

Tags: c#, regex

EDIT: I am using C#, I have read .NET-Regex can do this

I have a pattern like this:

```
name;a1;a2;a3
name;a1
```

It contains a name in the beginning and then a series of segments, but I they can have any number of occurrence.

I tried to solve this with

```
([^;]+)(?:;([stacp]\d+))+\n
```

but that only gets me the name and the last occurrence (but correctly matches the whole string), in the first example only "name" and "a3". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is splitting with a semi-colon an option? What is the environment/programming language?

Comment: In C#, you may access the capture stack. Your pattern is working well then.

Comment: The capture stack did the trick, thanks!